# how to remove statusbar animation when changing to fullscreen in Android

Tags: android, statusbar

when i change my activity to fullscreen, the statusbar performs an 
animation,but not disappear immediately. so how can i make the 
statusbar disappear immediate ? if need to change framework , where is 
it?

Comment: Friend, Have you found out which animation it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found solution.

we can out following code in activity from which we are creating and starting Intent

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
Intent scanIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(scanIntent);
```

By this it will hide status bar first then it will move to next activity.

Above code will require only when you are using single instance for second activity.
else you can apply solution given by Vineet Shukla

Answer (score 3):

try `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in the activity tag in your manifest file.

**Edit:**

Use `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` in your `onCreate()` before you call `setContentView ()` to set programmatically.

Comment: Please read question again "when i change my activity to fullscreen". I know how to set above flags. after setting above flags it shows animation to hide, not immediately.

Comment: @VineetShukla But it will not Help For Activity Which is declare as SingleInstance ,Means For First It will Work well ,but when we gain use Activity it will show status bar for Some Moment.