# Hiding/showing Status Bar without animation

Tags: android

I need to show / hide status bar in the same Activity(Fragment) for API 17+. Let's say one button will hide it, the other one will show it:

Show:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Hide:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

This works fine, but there is a "slide up-down" animation when it changes for full screen - not fullscreen. How to remove this animation? I want status bar to disappear immediately, I've tried with:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

But nothing happened, it is still showing up with animation, I've also read:

[how to remove statusbar animation when changing to fullscreen in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312029/how-to-remove-statusbar-animation-when-changing-to-fullscreen-in-android)
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/hS1twXVoorc

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? If so, could you please share. I've been struggling with this same thing for days now. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I didn't.

Comment: no problem, Djordje. Thanks for being willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this attribute in the activity or fragment layout, ideally under the root view

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
```